# Undefined symbols in .so

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I develop library and trying run tests.
When I run example building I got the undefined reference errors (in example one of that errors):

```
/opt/nt/lib/libntproto2db.so: undefined reference to ntproto::variant_t::TYPE::UINT8'
```

But, if I install same version with same commit from repository, which contains package built on the someone else machine, i have not received this error.

`nm` tool recognizes symbol as undefined, if library built on my machine:

```
$ nm -C -u /opt/nt/lib/libntproto2db.so | grep UINT8
                 U ntproto::variant_t::TYPE::UINT8
```

That is, if I build this library on another machine, then these symbols do not become undefined. Why?

I tried:

- Move `std::unordered_map` global `inline const` variable, that contains values of this type from `.h` to `.cc` file, that helped, but this is bad solution.
- Disable optimization `-O0`
- Check `$LIBRARY_PATH`, it's clear as a must be.
- View `ld` commandline during both builds (`make VERBOSE=1`), it is the same.

Comment: Voting as dupe, since this seems to be your own lib that's incorrect here. Probably the solution for static data members applies. [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: This is a distro problem, on docker it builds succesfully.
Probably, not one of the packages  on my distro is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a distro problem, on docker it builds succesfully. Probably, one of the packages on my distro have wrong version.